# make select2 multi-select not wrap to multiple lines

Tags: css, jquery-select2

Is there a way to make a multi-select not wrap when selecting enough values to do so? As an example, here's what it does:

[image]

What I want is for it to all be contained in one line and be accessible horizontally only. Select2 provides arrow key navigation as well as delete key usage so that isn't a big deal.

I figure this can probably be done with CSS but I'm struggling to figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: We're struggling too because we don't even know what your CSS + markup looks like.

Comment: @Diodeus the picture I linked was from [select2s example page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is :

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcc/735/

**CSS**:

```
.select2-choices{
    display:-webkit-inline-box;
}
```

**UPDATE** :

```
.select2-choices{
    display:-webkit-inline-box;
    max-width: 250px;   //  <--- set the max width you want
    //width: 250px;              or just force the width
}
```

**UPDATE N :**
Play with direction maybe :
http://jsfiddle.net/wEqLt/

---

**UPDATE FOR NEWEST VERSION:**
**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcc/735/

**CSS**:

```
.select2-selection__choice{
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

---

**UPDATE FOR VERSION 4.1:**
**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/srg2deo5/

**CSS**:

```
.select2-selection{
  overflow-y:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

ul.select2-selection__rendered{  
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I like this, but is there a way to constrain it to its current width while doing this?

Comment: I tried this, but it makes it difficult to select choices and maneuver the select box (ie, it doesn't insert the cursor at the end like I would expect).

Comment: is this some inherent shortcoming of select2, or is this just not possible?

Comment: that is close to usable. I'll play with it from there, but I think that's about as close as it'll get. Thanks.

Comment: I realize a long time has passed since this answer was posted. Nothing appears in the fiddle as far as I can tell. Is this still a solution?

Comment: @Hatshepsut Thanks for your reply, I've just updated the answer with link for newest version.

Comment: This doesn't work for the newest 4.1.0 version.

Comment: @JakubAdamec Here you go, Update for 4.1

Comment: @BENARDPatrick works great, thanks! Although it'd be better with the ellipsis and not inline scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
.select2-selection__choice {   
    /*float: left;*/ //remove float and add display: inline    
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple, 
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single,
.select2-selection .select2-selection--single{
   height:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Please provide explanation on how this will solve the issue so it can be more useful to users stumbling upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
.select2-selection__rendered {
    max-height: 80px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those working with Bootstrap and the `select2-bootstrap-5-theme`, I found that the cursor to enter the next option in the `<span class="select2-search select2-search--inline">...</span>` would always wrap on to a second line, doubling the height as soon as an option was selected. In case anyone comes here looking for that problem, here's how I fixed it:

```css
span.select2-selection.select2-selection--multiple {
  /* Display the choices and search input on one line, not wrapped */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

ul.select2-selection__rendered {
  /* Don't wrap the choices on to separate horizontal rows */
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

span.select2-selection__choice__display {
  /* Don't wrap text within selected choices */
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.select2-selection__rendered {
white-space:normal!important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.