# Change select2 multiple select style to selectpicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2, infinite-scroll, bootstrap-selectpicker

In select2 plugin multiple choices are appended to next line which directly enlarge the container element as it can be seen in first image,where as in bootstrap-select multiple choices are within the container and doesnt append to next line(Ref-Image 2).So thats why i want to change styling and UI of [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) plugin which is used for infinite scroller feature to [bootstrap-selectpicker](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-selectpicker).

Basically change first image below with second one.

I have tried `templateSelection` and `templateResult` of select2 but was not able to change style.

This is a select2 plugin with multiple selection

[image: select2]

This is a bootstrap-selectpicker

[image: bootstrap]

Comment: Please create a snippet here instead of use images

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You need to show us what you actually tried, instead of just _telling_ us that you tried something.

Comment: The `templateXX` of select2 allows you to change the *layout* (ie the HTML) of each item.   You likely also (or only) need to change the css.

Comment: To answer your issue, rather than your question: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464534/make-select2-multi-select-not-wrap-to-multiple-lines

Comment: You can also add css: `select2-selection__choice { display:none; }` to hide the pills.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have tried the solution earlier,problem with these solution is the size of scroller in 24 inch screen looks big and ugly